# Fail to update interface...(winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, label, partial

```
class2
{
    public void ExecuteAll(int rowStart,int columnStart,int rowEnd,int columnEnd)
    {
        ChessBoard chess = new ChessBoard();
        chess.YourTurn();
        counter++;
    }
 }

 public static int counter;
```

i have got this code, i want to print which players turn it is in the chess board. The counter is a static int, each time it is executed, the counter increases by 1.

YourTurn is a method in the partial class called ChessBoard. it looks like this:

```
public  void YourTurn()
{
    if (Class2.counter % 2 == 0)// if counter is an equal number
    {
        PlayerA.Text = "Black turn";// PlayerA label 
        PlayerA.Text = "White inactive";
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerB.Text = "White turn";// PlayerB label 
        PlayerB.Text = "Black inactive";
    }
}
```

what doesnt happen, is an update of the labels, each time i make a move. why is that?

---

even such design wont work, which means , it isnt because of a new instance created each time.

```
       public static string whitesTurn = "White turn";
    public static string blacksTurn = "Black turn";
    public  void YourTurn()
    {
        if (Class2.counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            PlayerA.Text = blacksTurn;
            PlayerA.Text = "White inactive";
            PlayerA.Invalidate();

        }
        else
        {
            PlayerB.Text = whitesTurn;
            PlayerB.Text = "Black inactive";
            PlayerA.Invalidate();

        }
    }
```

Comment: is counter defined inside class2? in our snippet it's outside.

Comment: Are you sure `ExecuteAll` is even being called?

Comment: Is ChessBoard class your form class? And is YourTurn function run on the UI thread?

Comment: class2 is my logic chess code. i use mvc model. executeAll is being called each time, yeah, each time i move a piece.. that method is like static main method in a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug your code and see if all the functions you've mentioned are called.

See if you are not trying to update values from non-UI thread.

Comment: i debugged it, the functinos are called and the counter changes in the partial class as expected. some labels are printed while other arent... :(

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating the controls would certainly help, but I am not 100% certain that you are updating the same instance of the class.

A better design would be to keep two string values inside your ChessBoard class (maybe `PlayerAText` and `PlayerBText`) that you would update instead.

Then, assuming `class1` is your WinForm, you could add a few pieces:

```
class2
{
  public void ExecuteAll(int rowStart,int columnStart,int rowEnd,int columnEnd)
  {
    ChessBoard chess = new ChessBoard();
    chess.YourTurn();
    counter++;
    PlayerA.Text = chess.PlayerAText;
    PlayerA.Text = chess.PlayerBText;
  }
}

public static int counter;
```

Comment: i had a suspicion that i created a new instance and it wouldnt work, but then if you look at YourTurn(), you will see that the counter is a static variable, and it wouldnt matter what the instance of the class would be... or am i wrong? cause when you create a new instance of the partial class, all the labels nullify as well?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of controls are PlayerA and PlayerB? If they're System.Windows.Forms.Label controls, try calling Invalidate() after you set the text:

```
PlayerA.Text = "Black turn";
PlayerA.Invalidate();
```

This will force the label to be redrawn.

Comment: i think i need to attach the function to a control. that will solve it

Answer (score 0):

You are not effectively changing anything

```
if (Class2.counter % 2 == 0)// if counter is an equal number
{
    PlayerA.Text = "Black turn";// PlayerA label 
    PlayerA.Text = "White inactive";
}
else
{
    PlayerB.Text = "White turn";// PlayerB label 
    PlayerB.Text = "Black inactive";
}
```

PlayerA.Text will always be "White inactive" and PlayerB.Text will "Black inactive"

I think the following will solve your problem

```
if (Class2.counter % 2 == 0)// if counter is an equal number
{
    PlayerA.Text = "Black turn";// PlayerA label 
    PlayerB.Text = "White inactive";
}
else
{
    PlayerB.Text = "White turn";// PlayerB label 
    PlayerA.Text = "Black inactive";
}
```

You should change labels A and B inside if and else both blocks

Comment: Holy smokes! Good catch! I wonder if the OP's code has this typo or if only the online example has the typo?

Comment: i dont understan nasmifive answer. what do i need to change to make the labels work?

Comment: @Dmitry: You affect text to the same label every time! Compare the 'PlayerA' and 'PlayerB'.

Comment: If you carefully see the if block PlayerA.Text being updated twice and in the else block PlayerB.Text twice, I think it's a typo and could be the reason why you don't get the desired results